# Load option dynamically - JQuery Select2

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-select2

Currently , I am trying to load dynamic options to select2 JQuery dropdown. These data are stored in another function, when user search for specific data it will call the other function and get data if exist. I don't want to use ajax because I am not calling an api request , it just a function written in C# and I am calling this function in Javascript. However I am not being able to display the matched options and the only way to call data dynamically is through ajax.

```
 $("#lnkIssue").select2({
            placeholder: 'Start typing...',
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            width: '100%',
            closeOnSelect: true,
            tags: false,
            allowClear: false,
            multiple: false,
            results:customFunction(params)
)}  


function(params)
{
   // Implementation
   return results = {id:'example-1',text:'example-2'}
}  // it didn't work
```

Is there a way to return results to select2 other than ajax function ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just pass the function into the `data` property

```
$("#lnkIssue").select2({
    placeholder: 'Start typing...',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
    width: '100%',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    tags: false,
    allowClear: false,
    multiple: false,
    data: getData()
  })

const getData = () => {
  return [{
    id: 'example-1',
    text: 'example-2'
  }]
}
```

Comment: true, but how can I get the params, data should match the search input.